# Combine multiple lists into a single list and output it for each row

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This example from documentation returns the commonMovies given a list of actors in which they all acted in.

https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/#_use_apoc_to_intersect_result_lists

Instead of returning just 1 row for the common movies, how can I return the actor name as well for example

```
Keanu Reeves, [Movie1,Movie2,Movie3]
Hugo Weaving, [Movie1,Movie2,Movie3]
Emil Eifrem, [Movie1,Movie2,Movie3]
```

The common movies list would be same for each row, it wouldn't make sense in this case, but I abstracted my problem down to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you could unwind the `names` list at the end to turn the names into individual rows. When doing so, you need to pass `names` to each `WITH` clause.

```sql
WITH ['Keanu Reeves', 'Hugo Weaving', 'Emil Eifrem'] as names
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WHERE p.name in names
WITH names, p, collect(m) as moviesPerActor
WITH names, collect(moviesPerActor) as movies
WITH names, reduce(commonMovies = head(movies), movie in tail(movies) |
 apoc.coll.intersection(commonMovies, movie)) as commonMovies
UNWIND names as name
RETURN name, commonMovies
```